# table of contents push chapters page numbers

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

How do I solve this problem?

When my `table of contents` takes more than one page, the second page is labeled as `page 1`. Then my `chapter 1` starts on `page 2` instead of `page 1`. Below I give the skeleton of my `.tex` file.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{book}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{roman}
\begin{titlepage}
   ...
\end{titlepage}
\chapter{Abstract}
 ...
\chapter{Preface}
 ...
\mainmatter
\pdfbookmark{Contents}{table}
\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Introduction}
 ....
\chapter{Two}
 ...
\backmatter
\chapter{Appendix}
  \label{chapter:appendix}
    \ldots
\end{document}
```

Any help?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: The table of contents appears in the main matter, thus the behavior is correct. The first chapter starts on the page after the table of contents. You have to run LaTeX 3 times to get the correct value for the pages in the table of contents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just remove `\pagenumbering{arabic}` at the end of the table of contents. `\tableofcontents` is set right after `\mainmatter`. That already restarts the page counter with arabic numbers:

```
\mainmatter
\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{table}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
```

Or if you want to put `\tableofcontents` in the front matter part:

```
\frontmatter
...
\chapter{Preface}
...
\cleardoublepage % get \pdfbookmark at the start of the table of contents
\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{table}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
```

BTW, also `\pagenumbering{roman}` can be removed, because this is already called by `\frontmatter`.

Comment: Thanks. This finally saves my hair, I couldn't stop scratching my head.